# Varias ImageView definidas src no xml, da erro java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:

Tags: android, xml, view, imageview

Tenho um `FrameLayout` que contém a lista de cursos com imagem dos respectivos cursos, tudo definido em XML, mas ocorre o erro.

São várias imagens, em torno de 15, com cerca 1280 x 1024 cada.

```xml
<ImageView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:src="@drawable/acucar"
     android:adjustViewBounds="true"
     android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.etec.etecapp, PID: 29787
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 33177612 byte allocation with 16770928 free bytes and 18MB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2738)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2643)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:152)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:140)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1008)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1067)
    at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:189)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at com.example.etec.etecapp.CursoTecnico.onCreateView(CursoTecnico.java:44)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2074)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1632)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:637)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1237)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1085)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1611)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18860)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5995)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18860)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5995)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18860)
    at android.view
```

Comment: Qual tamanho da imagem?

Comment: Manda a imagem, se possível.

Comment: imagem com 1280 x 1024 vai dar erro mesmo.
Já experimentou usar um image loader como o Glide, da bumptech?
Ele gerencia automaticamente o carregamento das imagens e impede esse out of memory error de ocorrer, independentemente do tamanho da imagem.

Comment: O erro tem haver com o tamanho das imagens. Antes de pensar utilizar qualquer *ap*i ou outro qualquer artificio(`android:largeHeap="true"` por exemplo), considere, se possível, usar imagens com um tamanho menor.

Answer (score 3):

`OutOfMemoryError` é o problema mais comum que ocorre no Android ao lidar com `bitmaps`. Este erro é acionado pela Java Virtual Machine (JVM) quando um objeto não pode ser alocado devido à falta de espaço de memória e também, o coletor de lixo não pode liberar algum espaço.

A princípio você pode adicionar no seu `AndroidManifest.xml` estas linhas `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`, `android:largeHeap ="true"` que funciona em algumas situações. Veja abaixo:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Vale a pena ler mais detalhes sobre [exibição eficiente de bitmap](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)<sup>(en)</sup> na documentação.

Você também pode dar uma lida sobre [carregamento eficiente de grandes *bitmaps*](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)<sup>(en)</sup>, que vai te ajudar melhor no tratamento desses arquivos.

**Observação**

Idealmente você estará usando `ARGB_8888` para bitmap. Isto significa que para cada pixel são atribuídos 4 bytes (cada um para A, R, G, B). Significa que ao carregar uma imagem de `1280x1024`, como você disse na pergunta,  que leva 1280 * 1024 * 4 = 5242880 B = 5242 KB = 5 MB.

[Resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32245018/2570426)